# Color or Highlight a data point in graph in winforms in visual studio using c# or cli/c++

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am drawing a graph in winform by picking data from my database. it works fine. What i need is that if some data value is greater than a max value then that point in the graph gets highlited or colored red. How can i do that?
Please help.

```
String^  constring = L"datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root;";
                 MySqlConnection^ conDataBase = gcnew MySqlConnection(constring);
                 MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase = gcnew MySqlCommand("select * from `data`.`test`;",conDataBase); 
                 MySqlDataReader^ myReader;

                 try{
                     conDataBase->Open();
                     myReader = cmdDataBase->ExecuteReader();
                    // MessageBox::Show("Data Inserted");
                     while(myReader->Read()){

                         String^ v_datetime;
                         String^ v_temp;
                         v_datetime = myReader->GetString("datetime");
                         v_pressure = myReader->GetInt32("temp").ToString();

                         String^ status;
                         if (myReader->GetInt32("temp") > 1000 && myReader->GetInt32("temp") < 50 )


 {
                                 status = " Abnormal ";
**// and this point only should be highlited or different color in the graph**
                                                             }
                         else{
                            status = " Normal";
                         }

                         this->label3->Text = status;

                         this->chart2->Series["Temperature"]->Points->AddXY(v_datetime,myReader->GetInt32("temp"));
                        // comboBox1->Items->Add(vName);

                     }
                 }catch(Exception^ex){
                     MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
                 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you add a property to the class that represent the object to be drawn, and when you draw your graph you test on this property and change color, shape and size.